# with numpy where: for black cell, putting new value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I am working with numpy in a csv file.

[image]

I have 3 columns. For 500 value in column 'PUMA', I wanted to put 5 in 'HTYPE' column. It worked with following code. But for a black cell(nan) in column 'PUMA'(3rd row), I wanted to put '-999' in the 'HTYPE' column. With the same code, it is not working.

How to put a value in a column, if there is nan in another column, using np.where?

```
    import pandas as pd, numpy as np
    df= pd.read_csv(input_folder + input_file )

    df['HTYPE'] = np.where(df['PUMA']==500, 5, df['HTYPE'] )
    df['HTYPE'] = np.where(df['PUMA']==np.NaN, -999, df['HTYPE'] )

    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need special function [`isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isna.html) for check `NaN`s values:

```
df['HTYPE'] = np.where(df['PUMA'].isna(), -999, df['HTYPE'] )
#for oldier versions of pandas
#df['HTYPE'] = np.where(df['PUMA'].isnull(), -999, df['HTYPE'] )
```

because by [design](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing):

```
np.nan == np.nan
False
```

Also instead double `np.where` is possible use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PUMA':[500,3302, np.nan, 9503],
                   'WGTP':[21,0,6,6],
                   'HTYPE':[20,0,0,0]})
print (df)
     PUMA  WGTP  HTYPE
0   500.0    21     20
1  3302.0     0      0
2     NaN     6      0
3  9503.0     6      0

df['HTYPE'] = np.select([df['PUMA']==500, df['PUMA'].isna()], 
                        [5, -999], 
                        default=df['HTYPE'] )
print (df)
     PUMA  WGTP  HTYPE
0   500.0    21      5
1  3302.0     0      0
2     NaN     6   -999
3  9503.0     6      0
```

Comment: Yes. I find np.select  perfect for my use. Thanks.